# How to make full text search with Linq2db?

Tags: .net, database, search, .net-core, linq2db

I have `.Net Core 2.2` project with `Linq2db` provider for `MySql`.

How can I make search using full text index with linq2db?

Is it possible to make for any DB Engine, not DB specific code?

Comment: We currently don't have any generic FTS API or implemented extensions for MySQL, but looking at MySQL documentation, I think you can implement it yourself. Just check existing test example for SQLite here https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/blob/master/Tests/Linq/Linq/FunctionTests.cs#L471 (MatchFtsTest test and SqlLite class with search method implementation).

Comment: Also you can track this issue https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/issues/1561

Comment: @DLuk Thanks for your answer, very needed function. I will track issue on github.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done like this:

```
using (var linqdb = new DatabaseModel())
{
    string searchFT = "wordToSearch*";
    List<TableClass> items = linqdb.GetTable<TableClass>().Where(wo => Sql.Ext.MySql().Match(MySqlExtensions.MatchModifier.Boolean, searchFT, wo.FistName, wo.LastName)).ToList();
}
```

Here is a link to the documentation:
https://linq2db.github.io/api/LinqToDB.DataProvider.MySql.MySqlExtensions.html

An example can be found here:
https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/blob/master/Tests/Linq/Linq/FullTextTests.MySql.cs

Answer (score 0):

As long as the database supports a text field which can support large amounts of text then you simply add an index to this field by doing somthing like:

class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet Blogs { get; set; }

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
        .HasIndex(b => b.Url);
}
```

}

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

In EF core if you use things like StartsWith, Contains or EF.Functions.Like in your Where functions then I believe this gets translated to a Like in SQL.  So in EF core this would use your full-text search for fields in such databases.

I think it should be the same for linq2db...

So yep this would be generic for any database.

However, as I once found out with SQLite I could not add an index to a such a text field with lots of data as the database does not support it... (from memory it was limited to around 1000 bytes roughly).

Comment: I see how can it can be made by MySql - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html , there written `match-against` syntax, not just like. so i think this need special translation by sql provider. May be this is only for `MySql`? Or I misunderstand something.

Comment: And in MySql this search need special Full Text Index.